# Traefik ingressroute returns 404 not found

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I'm using Traefik ingress controller. When I request to my domain `https://harbor.domain.com/` it returns 404 not found. what's wrong with my ingressroute?

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: harbor
  namespace: harbor
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`harbor.domain.com`) && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/service`) || PathPrefix(`/v2`) || PathPrefix(`/chartrepo`) || PathPrefix(`/c`))
      services:
        - kind: Service
          name: harbor-portal
          namespace: harbor
          port: 80
          scheme: https
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`notary.domain.com`)
      services:
        - kind: Service
          name: harbor-notary-server
          namespace: harbor
          port: 4443
          scheme: https
  tls:
    secretName: harbor.domain.com
```

Secret file exists and created by cluster issuer.
these are my services in harbor namespace:
[image: Services for harbor namespace]

Comment: Do other path work? Like `domain/api`? In [documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/entrypoints/#configuration-examples) ports are specified explicitly

Answer (score 0):

After resuming normal work following a day off, please refer to the configuration below:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: harbor-ingress
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
  - match: Host(`harbor.local`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: harbor-portal
      port: 80
  - match: Host(`harbor.local`) && PathPrefix(`/api/`, `/c/`, `/chartrepo/`, `/service/`, `/v2/`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: harbor-core
      port: 80
  tls:
    secretName: xx-tls-secret
```